# split int values in column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I currently have a dataset

| date_checkout_y | col |
| --- | --- |
| 18000809 | 5 |
| 18001017 | 6 |
| 18001226 | 8 |
| 18001229 | 8 |
| 18010216 | 10 |

I want to split date_checkout_y to create a datetime

tried

```py
df['date_checkout_y'] = df.date_checkout_y.str.split(n=1,expand=True)
```

but getting an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use from apply method (if your col is string else convert it to string)

```py
from datetime import datetime
def f(x):
    return datetime(year=x[:4], month=x[4:6], day=x[6:8]

df['new'] = df['date_checkout_y'].apply(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following code snippet provides you with the results you desire:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['18000809     5'], ['18001017     6'], ['18001226     8'], ['18001229     8'], ['18001229     8']], columns=['date_checkout_y'])

print(df)

df2 = df.date_checkout_y.str.split(n=1,expand=True)

df2.columns = ['Date', 'Value']

print(df2)
```

When I ran this "proof of principle" program with data that mimicked yours, this was the result I got on my terminal.

```
  date_checkout_y
0  18000809     5
1  18001017     6
2  18001226     8
3  18001229     8
4  18001229     8
       Date Value
0  18000809     5
1  18001017     6
2  18001226     8
3  18001229     8
4  18001229     8
```